# Html Textinput in Table Data

Tags: javascript, html

Our teacher want us to create a website that will recieve text from the user (textfield) and send it to table data and it need to be in `<form>`

When i use `<form>` i input text in textfield the text and submit it the text that i enter is showing in table data at the same time its gone like in the text field i know that this is because of `<form>` when i remove the `<form>` the text is showing in table data.

Here is my code :

```
<form>
  Name:   <input action="f1.document.getElementById("first_name");"  id="first_name" size="30"  type="text" >

<button class="okok" name="myBtn" type="submit"  value="Submit Data" onClick="ajax_post();">COMPUTE </button>
                    </form> 

<table>
<tr>    

 <td style="color:white;" id=f1  >   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

in script 
 :

```
function ajax_post(){




    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
   var table = document.getElementById("f1");
   table.innerText = fn;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the button is 'submitting' the form, which is like refreshing to page in that it will clear the values.

You have to stop the form submitting, like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: my teacher want is   the text from the input will remain at table data but in textfield it need to be blank

Comment: So in your ajax_post function as well as adding the input to the table data, also clear the input box:

document.getElementById("input-box").value = "";

Comment: hmm.. yeah ... exactly

Comment: ....so does that answer your question? If so, please mark the answer as correct. If not, let us know what else is wrong, thanks